# Android can't get Texview content to share intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm working on a share button to share the current item image and content but i cant seen to get the text from the texView id to work on Intent Share.
I was wondering if anybody knows a better method?

```
btnShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    View content = findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
    content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/image.jpg");
        try {
            cachePath.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
            ostream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        TextView tittle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtText);
        TextView txtSubText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSubText);
        TextView txtDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);


        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, tittle);
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, txtSubText);
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, txtDescription);
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(cachePath));
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"This was share via Almas's Delicias");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Share via"));
```

Comment: To get a `TextView`'s text as a `String`, you need to call `getText().toString()` on it. As you have it now, you're attempting to attach the `TextView`s themselves as extras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this lines of codes:

```
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, tittle.getText().toString());
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, txtSubText.getText().toString());
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, txtDescription.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Glad to hear that!